# Laravel API design

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns, api, laravel

I've been designing and coding my Laravel API boilerplate for couple days now, and I'd like to hear some advice/improvement hints!

I'm pretty satisfied with the result, but I'm also aware, there might be (and surely are) some things that can be improved.

Basic concept:

Every controller should extend my `App\Http\Controllers\ApiController` (actually, I'm thinking about moving this controller to `App\Support\Http\Controllers\ApiController`):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Support\Http\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

abstract class ApiController extends Controller
{
    protected static $repository = null;
    protected static $transformer = null;
    protected static $storeRequest = null;
    protected static $updateRequest = null;

    public function index()
    {
        $instances   = $this->repository()->all();
        $transformed = $this->transformer()->collection($instances);

        return response()->ok($transformed);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $instance    = $this->repository()->show($id);
        $transformed = $this->transformer()->item($instance);

        return response()->ok($transformed);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateStoreRequest();

        $this->repository()->store($request->input());

        return response()->created();
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validateStoreRequest();

        $this->repository()->update($id, $request->input());

        return response()->updated();
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->repository()->destroy($id);

        return response()->destroyed();
    }

    private function validateStoreRequest()
    {
        app(
            static::$storeRequest ?: app('naming')->parse(static::class)->storeRequest()
        );
    }

    private function validateUpdateRequest()
    {
        app(
            static::$storeRequest ?: app('naming')->parse(static::class)->updateRequest()
        );
    }

    private function transformer()
    {
        return app(
            static::$transformer ?: app('naming')->parse(static::class)->transformer()
        );
    }

    private function repository()
    {
        return app(
            static::$repository ?: app('naming')->parse(static::class)->repository()
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, every **"entity"** should have it's own transformer with should extends my `App\Support\Transformer`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Support;

abstract class Transformer
{
    abstract public function item($item);

    public function collection($collection)
    {
        $transformed = [];

        foreach($collection as $item) {
            $transformed[] = $this->item($item);
        }

        return $transformed;
    }
}
```

`Transfomer::item($item)` basically returns a transformed array (I'm looking forward to implicit return types in PHP7!)

Next, every **"entity"** should have its own repository, which should extend my `App\Support\Repository`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Support;

abstract class Repository
{
    public function all()
    {
        $model = $this->model();

        return $model::all();
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $model = $this->model();

        return $model::findOrFail($id);
    }

    public function store(array $attributes)
    {
        $model = $this->model();

        return $model::create($attributes);
    }

    public function update($id, array $attributes)
    {
        $model = $this->model();

        return $model::findOrFail($id)
                        ->update($attributes);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $model = $this->model();

        return $model::findOrFail($id)
                        ->delete();
    }

    private function model()
    {
        return app('naming')->parse(static::class)
                            ->model();
    }
}
```

And of course, every **"entity"** must have it's own model, but I haven't created any `BaseModel` class yet. I do not find it necessary right now.

As you can see in the `ApiController`, I've created some custom *response macros* that correspond to HTTP status codes.

You might be curious about `app('naming')`, but all that does, is that is transforms any class name (also full namespaced) to corresponding class for given **"entity"**.

Also, any validation is managed through Laravel's `FormRequest` class.

All in all, are there any approaches that you consider badly implemented? Is there anything that breaks SOLID principals? Is there anything I could improve on? Any breaks PSR-2 formatting?

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: This is version 5.1.11

Answer (score 2):

- Why $repository and $transformer are static?
- Seems like $storeRequest and $updateRequest are just validators - do you really need to have them static?
- No type hinting for methods of `abstract class Transformer` ?

Comment: * not sure! they are only accessed within object context, so they should not be static
* nope, same as **1.**
* I wanted to be able to pass them both array and collection, but I might change it to only acception Collection